# How to reload component when URL is changed in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React Application I need to reload the component when it comes to the path `path="/"`. I know `react-router` helps us reload easily the current component but I really need this in my application for some styling purpose. In my application I have two paths:

```
<Route path="/" component={newRoute}/>
```

and `<Route path="/gallery" component={GalleryImages}/>`. So, whenever I move from `GalleryImages` to `newRoute` I need to reload the `newRoute` components otherwise the styles are not working. What is the way around here? Here's my`App.js` now:

```js
const newRoute = () => {
  return (
    <div id="colorlib-page">
      <div id="container-wrap">
        <div id="colorlib-main">
          <Introduction/>
          <About/>
          <Projects/>
          <Timeline/>
          <Blog/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Sidebar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={newRoute} exact/>
          <Route path="/gallery" component={GalleryImages} exact/>
          <Route component={Error}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: have you tried using `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class component instead of functional component

Comment: Did that but still the same @owaislatif